# Please reconsider the closing of this question and reopen it for a response that actually answers the question

Tags: discussion, pronunciation

Look at the question that was asked here and not sufficiently answered: [What is the difference between "phonetic" and "phonemic"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104224/what-is-the-difference-between-phonetic-and-phonemic)

The question is asking whether there is a difference between phonetic and phonemic transcription. In the responses, there is no indication of how either is transcribed in phrase format. For example, would phonemic transcription be /'sæd 'deɪ/ and phonetic transcription be [sæd de] in IPA?

Comment: I suppose in the context of a potentially ambiguous *written* form, such as *These are the toys I have to play with*, including the stress mark could be considered "phonemic" (if ***have*** is stressed, I *must* play with them; if not, they're simply *available* to be played with). But I don't know if that's really the issue here. The fundamental difference between what phonetic/phonemic transcriptions actually *represent* should be easily established by considering the definitions themselves, but it's quite true that no existing answers specifically address *how* they're transcribed...

Comment: ...but as [this discussion](http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/3450-difference-between-phonemic-and-phonetic-transcription) points out, the difference there is that phonetic transcription puts **[each sound]** in square brackets, whereas phonemic transcription puts **/each phoneme/** in backslashes. It also gives an example of a context where the actual sound and the phoneme are different (in Japanese - I suspect no such example would be meaningful to native Anglophones in English).

Comment: ...but I'm voting to re-open, if only because I'd like to know if it's feasible that **prince** and **prints**, for example, are the same in phonetic transcription, but different in phonemic transcription, as appears to be suggested [in this discussion](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/pronunciation-prince-prints-and-similar.35322/#post-262348)

Comment: sure, why not, it's an interesting question so good to have more perspectives.